Blender 4.1 right click moving changes, how to revert it to how it was on previous versions?
Previously, when you had Select with mouse button set to Right button, you could pick any object/vertex/edge/face and just move the one you clicked on, but now they changed it so that if you select multiple things, and then click on one of those things, it will move all of the selected things instead of just the one you clicked on. So it now pretty much works exactly the same as pressing G.
Tried to play with the settings on Keymap -> Object mode -> Move, especifically the Connected setting since on previous blender versions that's pretty much the only difference between both Move commands (the one with G and the one with mouse drag). Activated the Connected option, unchecked it and it's still not working. I don't know if it is a bug or if it it's something that has just happened on my blender, but it makes it so that now editing stuff feels so much more clunkier.
